# JSON Read/Write Error: Application Does Not Take Parameters

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to write a Read/Write value for a case class for which many of the values might be null. Following the Play Framework's tutorials I write it as

```
implicit val incomingMessageWrites: Writes[IncomingMessage] = (
        (JsPath \ "stageNum").write[Int] and
        (JsPath \ "stage").write[String] and
        (JsPath \ "stageTime").write[Long] and
        (JsPath \ "vendorId").write[String] and
        (JsPath \ "text").writeNullable[String] and
        (JsPath \ "campaignCode").writeNullable[String] and
        (JsPath \ "osTotals").writeNullable[OSTotals] and
        (JsPath \ "splitSegment").writeNullable[Int] and
        (JsPath \ "segmentNum").writeNullable[Int] and
        (JsPath \ "osBatchStatus").writeNullable[OSBatchStatus]
    )(unlift(IncomingMessage.unapply))
```

However, I keep encountering the same issue where IntelliJ tells me that the uplift method doesn't work because "Application Does Not Take Parameters".

The case class for this is

```
case class IncomingMessage(
  stageNum: Int,
  stage: String,
  stageTime: Long,
  vendorId: String,
  text: String,
  campaignCode: String,
  osTotals: OSTotals,
  splitSegment: Int,
  segmentNum: Int,
  osBatchStatus: OSBatchStatus) {

    def this(stageNum: Int, stage: String, stageTime: Long, vendorId: String, text: String, campaignCode: String) =
      this(stageNum, stage, stageTime, vendorId, text, campaignCode, null, 0, 0, null)

    def this(stageNum: Int, stage: String, stageTime: Long, splitSegment: Int, vendorId: String, text: String, campaignCode: String) =
      this(stageNum, stage, stageTime, vendorId, text, campaignCode, null, splitSegment, 0, null)

    def this(stageNum: Int, stage: String, stageTime: Long, segmentNum: Int, vendorId: String) =
      this(stageNum, stage, stageTime, vendorId, null, null, null, 0, segmentNum, null)

    def this(stageNum: Int, stage: String, stageTime: Long, segmentNum: Int, vendorId: String, osTotals: OSTotals) =
      this(stageNum, stage, stageTime, vendorId, null, null, osTotals, 0, segmentNum, null)

    def this(stageNum: Int, stage: String, stageTime: Long, vendorId: String, oSBatchStatus: OSBatchStatus) =
      this(stageNum, stage, stageTime, vendorId, null, null, null, 0, 0, osBatchStatus)

}
```

The same thing happens for the other case class

```
case class OSBatchStatus(os: String, success: Int, failure: Int)

object OSBatchStatus {
  implicit val oSBatchStatusReads: Reads[OSBatchStatus] = (
    (JsPath \ "os").readNullable[String] and
      (JsPath \ "success").readNullable[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "failure").readNullable[Int]
    )(OSBatchStatus.apply _)
}
```

I've written Read and Write values, but have omitted them to save space.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are optional fields in your input JSON file, then the corresponding fields of your case class should be optional as well. Your definition of `Reads` for `OSBatchStatus` assumes that all fields are optional, so your case class should look like this:

```
case class OSBatchStatus(os: Option[String], success: Option[Int], failure: Option[Int])
```

The same rules apply to your `IncomingMessage` case class (four fields are obligatory and every other should be an `Option[T]`). Moreover, since the fields in your JSON file have exactly the same names as the fields in your case class, you can use play-json methods that will autogenerate `Reads/Writes/Format` for you:

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json._

implicit val incomingMessageWrites = Json.writes[IncomingMessage]
implicit val osBatchStatusReads    = Json.reads[OSBatchStatus]
implicit val osTotalsFormat        = Json.format[OSTotals] // Will generate both `Reads` and `Writes`
```

Comment: This sorted out my problem. Thank you